# PID: 30172 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "64‎"

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I don't understand the reason behind this exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.khalid_al_mustadi.jockeystickers, PID: 30172
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "64‎"
```

All I am doing is

```
if (Integer.parseInt(groupnameList.get(position).get("Value_C").trim().replace("%", "")) >= 70)
```

Comment: Separating out what is inside your parseInt might help you determine why it can't parse the results of that

Comment: First try to debug whats exactly is the value of  -- groupnameList.get(position).get("Value_C").trim().replace("%", "")

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, it seems you  are trying to parse -

```
Integer.parseInt("\"64\""));
```

which means `groupnameList.get(position).get("Value_C").trim().replace("%", "")` gives you - `"\"64\"" (a string "64" with the double quotes included)`

And double quotes(") cannot be converted to integers which is why you get `NumberFormatException`.
Remove any double quotes prior to using `Integer.parseInt()` .